# Infinite Squares in Sequence

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that if an arithmetic sequence has a square, there are an infinite amount of squares in the sequence.

Trivial Progress: If the first term is $a$, the difference is $d$, and $a+kd$ is a square, then $a^2+2kd+k^2d^2$. I know I have to create another square in the sequence, but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n^2=a+kd $ then for all $h\in\Bbb N$ you have that $(n+hd)^2=n^2+d(2hn+h^2d)=a+d(k+2hn+h^2d)$ is in the sequence

Answer (score 4):

Given an arithmetic sequence with difference $d$ and with $s=m^2$ in the sequence,

can you show that $(m+nd)^2$ is in the sequence for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let the sequence have first term $a$ and common difference $d$.  So let the k-th term $a_k$ be $a +kd$. Suppose the $k_0$-th term is a perfect square $s^2$. Then let's consider some element in the progression $i$ terms later. It's $s^2+id$. When this is a perfect square, $m$ we have $s^2+id = m^2$. If we choose $m$ so that $m \equiv \pm s \pmod d$, then for some integer $i$, this equation can be satisfied. Taking all such $m$ gives infinitely many perfect squares. This assumes the artihmetic progression is in the integers. If if we're in the rationals, it has some subsequence of integers, and the same logic applies. In the reals, the progression with first term 4 and common difference $\sqrt 2$ is a counterexample.